# General questions about OpenBSD source code and release dates

Tags: history, openbsd

Looking into doing analysis of the lifespan of a line of code, and via another question on stackexchange I was pointed to a [research paper on OpenBSD](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~stuart/papers/usenix06.pdf) that I've got a few questions about.

That being:

- When was OpenBSD source code release as opensource?
- In this sentence, "**We learn that 61% of the lines of code in today’s OpenBSD are foundational: they were introduced prior to the release of the initial version we studied and have not been altered since."**

  - does that mean that OpenBSD released the very first batch of source code in "19 May 1998" (see next question for date info),
  - or that's just the release they decided to start the 7.5 years of source code review?
  - If "19 May 1998" was the first release, where did the other 61% of the code base come from,
  - and was that never posted to an open source version control system?
- When that 7.5 years was appears be stated in this sentence: **"We compiled a database of 140 vulnerabilities reported in the 7.5 years between 19 May 1998 and 17 November 2005."**

  - where would I find the source code for the patches in those 7.5 years,
  - do those dates match releases dates,
  - if so, how to I figure that out on my own?

Reason I ask all of this is in part because I can't find the information on [OpenBSD](http://www.openbsd.org/) or [Chuck Cranor](http://chuck.cranor.org/)'s website, which states:

> I also hosted and helped create the
>   first Anonymous CVS server on the
>   Internet (the original
>   anoncvs.openbsd.org, which was also
>   know as eap.ccrc.wustl.edu).

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenBSD) states "Initial release: 1 October 1996", but I'm unable to tell if that release was open source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> does that mean that OpenBSD released the very first batch of source code in "19 May 1998"

No, the first public release of OpenBSD was made in July 1996. ([Source 1](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Openbsd))

19 May 1998 means your paper's authors used OpenBSD 2.3 as their starting point. ([Source 2](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Timeline_of_OpenBSD)) I don't see any special reason to begin with this release. The explanation is probably something trivial; perhaps that was the oldest version they could readily lay hands on.

> where did the other 61% of the code base come from,

NetBSD. (Same sources as above.)

> was that never posted to an open source version control system?

The [OpenBSD CVS repository](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/) appears to have been in continuous operation for the ~15 years of the project. I fully expect that you could check out OpenBSD 1.x from there if you wanted.

> where would I find the source code for the patches in those 7.5 years,

The CVS repository.

> do those dates match releases dates,

See Source 2.

> I'm unable to tell if that release was open source.

OpenBSD has always been Open Source. It was a fork of NetBSD, which was itself Open Source.

Comment: You can find out when the repository was created by checking the logs of e.g. [`/CVSROOT/modules`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/CVSROOT/modules): 1995-10-14 00:20:55. Looking at a file that's been there since the beginning, e.g. [`/src/bin/cat/Makefile`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/bin/cat/Makefile), shows the `initial import of NetBSD tree` on 1995-10-18 and all the release tags.